# Como consumir API do GitHub no VS2019 evitando erro 403 em todas as requisições?

Tags: c#, .net, api, github

Alguém me salva por favor.  Preciso consumir a API do GitHub para um desafio de estagio, porém to travado num problema a 2 dias, o desafio deixa explicito que não é para usar autenticações, apenas usar a API aberta. Esse abaixo é o codigo que to usando que peguei do Macoratti.
O problema é que sempre que tento acessar a URI por dentro do VS2019 ele retorna 403 Forbidden, mas se acessar a mesma URi pelo navegar ele abre normal, pelo insominia mesma coisa, testei com uma outra API aberta qualquer e recebo o retorno 200 com o Json com esse mesmo codigo abaixo apenas substituindo o parametro do objeto response.

Alguem sabe como resolver?

```
 static async Task Main()
        {
            // Create an HttpClientHandler object and set to use default credentials
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            
            // Create an HttpClient object
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

            // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
            try
            {
                
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/");
                
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }

            // Need to call dispose on the HttpClient and HttpClientHandler objects
            // when done using them, so the app doesn't leak resources
            handler.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Tente remover o try-catch e ver o que a exceção lhe informa.

Comment: Aliás, é só você ver a resposta HTTP.

Comment: "Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve especificar um User agent no header. Apenas adicionando o código abaixo após a inicialização de seu HttpClient deve funcionar

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "request");
```